# Seam on edges of displacement map on rope

Tags: uv, subdivision-surface, displacement

I've been following BlenderGuru's tutorial on ropes (https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=1drRNphACMc). It's a bit outdated but I've managed to get past some of the differences introduced in 2.8.

However, I have ran into a problem. My rope seems to have weird seams on the edges where the cylinders connect. I've checked and I don't have any double faces or vertices and the UV map lines up properly to each edge using 'Selected to Pixels'.

[image: Seams with Shading Nodes]

[image: UV Map]

[image: Subdivision modifier]

[image]

Is there something added in 2.8 that I need to change? I'm really not sure what the problem could be.

Comment: your texture is not completely seamless, so get a seamless one....

Comment: The thing is that I’m using the same texture as the one in the tutorial, and in the tutorial he did not get any seams, it all worked perfectly.

Comment: hmmm, recheck the node setup in his tutorial...

Comment: Is the 'Merge' distance in your _Array_ modifier set high enough to weld the joins between elements?

Answer (score 1):

so the problem here is that your texture isn‘t seamless which you can fix by making it seamless in an imageprocessing software like gimp
here is a youtube tutorial how to do that

https://youtu.be/qAXRDfDaJMk

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I solved the issue. Thanks [Robin Betts](https://blender.stackexchange.com/users/35559/robin-betts) for the help. Just as he said, the problem was with the merge distance. Increased that and the seams are gone!

Thank you very much for the help everyone.